# Nuget no longer able to find package versions

Tags: .net, nuget

My build server suddenly started failing all builds when running `nuget restore`, with errors for all packages.  These package versions exist, and have been working fine until the last week or so.

```
NuGet Version: 5.6.0.6591
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.6.0.22303' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
MSBuild P2P timeout [ms]: 120000
<long MSBuild output>

Restoring NuGet package NLog.4.6.2.
Restoring NuGet package FluentAssertions.3.0.107.
Restoring NuGet package Mindscape.Raygun4Net.5.0.0.
WARNING: Unable to find version '3.0.107' of package 'FluentAssertions'.
WARNING: Unable to find version '4.6.2' of package 'NLog'.
WARNING: Unable to find version '5.0.0' of package 'Mindscape.Raygun4Net'.
WARNING: Unable to find version '4.6.2' of package 'NLog'.
WARNING: Unable to find version '3.0.107' of package 'FluentAssertions'.
WARNING: Unable to find version '5.0.0' of package 'Mindscape.Raygun4Net'.

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5179f1a1ebd4ddaa\src\.nuget\NuGet.Config
    C:\Users\<my name>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
```

[image]

I found a Nuget blog post about removing support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1, so I updated the server to only use TLS 1.2;  this did not fix the issue.  I am not sure how else to diagnose why nuget is unable to find the package versions.

Comment: Restore with detailed verbosity to see if it gives any hints. Note that text is easier to read if you copy and paste, rather than taking a screenshot (although we lose color)

Comment: MSBuild 14 shipped with VS 2015, I believe... you may well just need to upgrade to a newer version of MSBuild.

Comment: Ok @JonSkeet, I'll try that.  Did not expect MSBuild to impact nuget package fetching

Comment: It could be a red herring - it's just that as it's shown in the log, it's something to check out

Comment: Worth a shot.  Updated MSBuild, still no nice

Comment: I would check what is in NuGet.Config - maybe there is a bad link to nuget repo or other option which fails.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue, branch code did not change at all, before build was ok(3 weeks ago), triggered it once again yesterday and failed. In my case updating NuGet to latest version helped, before had old version 3.3.0.212, now have 5.6.0.6591 and it works, maybe try to install other nuget version(older for example and check). No other changes have been made, except nuget.exe update to latest.

[Old nuget version errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXFDt.png)